# PowerApps Date Formatting

Tags: powerapps

I am working on a PowerApp, and the date formatting is working for almost all of my fields, but there is one that is a calculated field in Sharepoint. This calculated date for the new email comes 28 days after the last email. I've been able to format all my dates normally before, but this one is not working. Does anyone know why?
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4hdl.png)

Comment: can you not use `Text( DateTimeValue( ThisItem.NextEmail ), "mm/dd/yyyy" )`
[Reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text)

Answer (score 0):

That *is* interesting. It looks like you're doing everything right in PowerApps. May be a bug with calculated columns.

As a potential workaround, try formatting the date in the Sharepoint column itself.

Looks like [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators) would do the trick:

`toLocaleDateString(): returns a language sensitive` `representation of just the date portion of a date`

`- "txtContent":"=toLocaleDateString(@now)" results` `vary based on user's locale, but en-us looks like` `"2/5/2019"`